# Control elements not by name with COM “InternetExplorer.Application” object

Tags: php, javascript, html, com

I have a example page (http://****.com/def.php") code is:

```
<form action="abc.php" method="POST" name="f_action">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="password" name="pwd">
<input type="submit" value="OK" name="action">
</form>
```

and I used php with COM “InternetExplorer.Application” object to fill and submit the form:

```
$Browser = new COM('InternetExplorer.Application');
$Browserhandle = $Browser->HWND;
$Browser->Visible = true;
$f1_url = "http://**.com/def.php";
$Browser->Navigate($f1_url);
sleep(5);
$Browser->Document->f_action->id->focus();
$Browser->Document->f_action->id->value = $p_user_name;
$Browser->Document->f_action->pwd->focus();
$Browser->Document->f_action->pwd->value = $p_user_pwd;
$Browser->Document->f_action->action->focus();
$Browser->Document->f_action->action->click();
```

It can work and easy to use by name attribute!
BUT if I change the part of example page code to this:

```
<form action="abc.php" method="POST">
```

Change "name='f_action'" to "**NO name attribute**", How can I do to fill and submit the form with COM “InternetExplorer.Application” object and php?

Thank you and sorry for my poor English.